# Doing a job between two times by android AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to start  and finish a repetitive task by android AlarmManager, but i can only start it in the Specified time.
How can i set end time for tasks
sample:
start 8:15
**Finish 21:45**

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,8);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,15);

long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();

Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, i, 0);

am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,pi);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify ending time for alarm manager but what you can do is that you can check the current time and decide whether you will do the task or not. So if time passed 21:45 you just simply don't do anything or cancel it.